# Pycharm importing modules from sibling directory

Tags: pycharm, python-import

My project directory is

[image]

"`app`", "`framework`" and "`models`" directory are the places where i am writing my code and all these have  `__init__.py` file.

Now i am trying to import the modules written in `framework` and `models` directory from python code whithin "`app`" directory.

```
from framework.request_handler import Shelf
from models.books import Books
```

However i am getting unresolved reference. Even the following fails.

```
from ..framework.request_handler import Shelf 
from ..models.books import Books
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: relative imports ? `from . import framework`

Comment: just tried it. Getting "Unresolved Reference 'framework". :(

Comment: oups sorry `..` instead of `.`

Comment: yeah i tried even that. it wouldnt work.

Comment: I found answer MMF. I had to mark "default" as my source directory. Thanks for helping !!